# fcitx doesn't have any input methods

Tags: language-support, input-language, japanese, fcitx

On Ubuntu 18.04.4

When I open fcitx configuration there are no input languages in the box by default, and when I press the "+" button nothing even pops up inside of its box. What do I need to download for things to appear?

[image]

Trying to download the Japanese language, just FYI.

Comment: Generally Fcitx is difficult to use on Ubuntu 18.04. Have you considered to use IBus instead, and use e.g. `ibus-mozc`?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo fcitx-mozc`. After this Open System Settings > Language Support and download Japanese language (automatic)`reboot`, do this several times, if the selection is not available. Also as @Gunnar told you that use `ibus-mozc` or `uim-mozc`

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in a comment, I also recommend `fcitx-mozc`

very good. `anthy` works well as well

this is the packages I have installed in 20.04

```
fcitx/focal,focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 all [installed,automatic]
fcitx-bin/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fcitx-config-common/focal,focal,now 0.4.10-3 all [installed,automatic]
fcitx-config-gtk/focal,now 0.4.10-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fcitx-data/focal,focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 all [installed,automatic]
fcitx-dbus-status/focal,now 2016062301-3 amd64 [installed]
fcitx-frontend-all/focal,focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 all [installed,automatic]
fcitx-frontend-gtk2/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fcitx-frontend-gtk3/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fcitx-frontend-qt5/focal,now 1.2.4-1build2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fcitx-hangul/focal,now 0.3.1-2 amd64 [installed]
fcitx-m17n/focal,now 0.2.4-2 amd64 [installed]
fcitx-module-dbus/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fcitx-module-kimpanel/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fcitx-module-lua/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fcitx-module-x11/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fcitx-modules/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed]
fcitx-mozc/focal,now 2.23.2815.102+dfsg-8ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
fcitx-pinyin/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fcitx-table/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fcitx-table-emoji/focal,focal,now 0.2.4-2 all [installed]
fcitx-ui-classic/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fcitx-ui-qimpanel/focal,now 2.1.3-2build1 amd64 [installed]
fcitx5-module-quickphrase-editor/focal,now 1.2.4-1build2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libfcitx-config4/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libfcitx-core0/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libfcitx-gclient1/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libfcitx-qt5-1/focal,now 1.2.4-1build2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libfcitx-qt5-data/focal,focal,now 1.2.4-1build2 all [installed,automatic]
libfcitx-utils0/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

hope this helps